# How can I hand over CD audio data read by cdparanoia to the ALSA player?

Tags: c++, alsa, cdda

I'm trying to playback an audio CD by using `cd_paranoia` (from the `cdio` package) and to hand over the data read to the ALSA sound output. Buffered, of course. My issue is now the following: As stated in [this example program](https://github.com/rocky/libcdio-paranoia/blob/master/example/C%2B%2B/paranoia.cpp), a call to `paranoia_read ()` returns an `int16_t*` containing one sector (2,352 bytes) of audio data, which can be then cast into a `char*`.

The ALSA `snd_pcm_writei ()` method, on the other hand needs a chunk of audio data in a `char*`, whose length is to be determined by using the `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size ()` method, which basically returns the count of bytes sent to the sound device, until it triggers an interrupt. Sell also [this example sourcecode](https://gist.github.com/ghedo/963382/815c98d1ba0eda1b486eb9d80d9a91a81d995283#file-sound_playback-c-L97).

The two methods will almost for sure return different values 'cause an ALSA frame has a different size than a CD sector. This would mean I'd have to divide the data `cd-paranoia` delivers me somehow, so that they will fit into ALSA's frame structure. Or would it be sufficient just to stream the CD audio data into a big byte array (`std::queue<char>`) and then, step by step, read as many bytes from this array, so that I will get a complete ALSA "frame"?

Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: I hope you get an answer, but this seems to be way too specialized in a dying technology.

Comment: Well…I wasn't exactly asking for whether CD playback makes sense at all…

Answer (score 0):

`snd_pcm_writei()` handles any number of frames.

Comment: …but the smallest unit of sound data `snd_pcm_writei()` handles is one frame, right?

Comment: You could also call it with zero frames, but that would be pointless …